# Magento 2: How to assign a category to CMS page?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, cms-pages

How to redirect a category page to CMS page in Magento 2? I have tried several methods by using URL-rewrite but these methods work only on Magento 1.

Comment: It should work. Try to clear Cache and try again.

Comment: i cleared it. did not work.

Answer (score -2):

This module solved my problem.
[Category Redirect](https://github.com/Mestrona/Mestrona_CategoryRedirect)